# firebase.json redirects section ignored

Tags: firebase, api, redirect, web-applications, firebase-hosting

I am trying to call an API from a WebApp hosted on firebase.

The API is at:

```
https://<Server ip>:4446/WebShop/WebShop.asmx/GetItemsInfo
```

I have the following firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [{
      "source": "/WebShop/:path*",
      "destination":"https://webapp.all4shop.co.il:4446/:path",
      "type": 302
    }]
  }
}
```

It seems that firebase in ignoring the redirect section.
Inspecting the http call fire base calls "Request URL: [https://item-inspector.web.app/WebShop"](https://item-inspector.web.app/WebShop%22) and not redirecting the call to my server, where the API is served from.

Any help on why that is happening will be appreciated.

Thanks

Erez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is a limitation built into Firebase.

To use redirect you have to upgrade your fee "Spark" Firebase plan one level up to a "Blaze" Pay As You Go plan.